# Remove node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule taint

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubeadm

What CLI command can I type to remove the `node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule` taint from the master node in a Kubernetes cluster?

The following command is failing:

```
[lnxcfg@ip-10-0-0-193 ~]$ kubectl taint nodes $(kubectl get nodes --selector=node-role.kubernetes.io/master | awk 'FNR==2{print $1}') key:node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule-
error: invalid taint effect: node-role.kubernetes.io/master, unsupported taint effect
```

As you can see below, I am able to get the name of the master node successfully by using the following command, which is also embedded in the above failing command:

```
[lnxcfg@ip-10-0-0-193 ~]$ kubectl get nodes --selector=node-role.kubernetes.io/master | awk 'FNR==2{print $1}'
ip-10-0-0-193.us-west-2.compute.internal
```

This is an AWS Linux 2 node hosting the master node of a single master Kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 30):

```
kubectl taint nodes $(hostname) node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule-
```

But you can also schedule on master node without removing the taint:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
...
  spec:
...
    spec:
...
      tolerations:
        - key: "node-role.kubernetes.io/master"
          effect: "NoSchedule"
          operator: "Exists"
```

Answer (score 10):

Below command can be used to remove taint from node.

```
kubectl taint nodes controlplane node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule-
```

Answer (score 7):

you can edit node configuration and comment the taint part.

```
kubectl edit node <node_name>
```

once you comment the taint json and exit. It would update the node.

Answer (score 0):

as per documentation  https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#taint

this should work.

```
kubectl taint nodes $(kubectl get nodes --selector=node-role.kubernetes.io/master | awk 'FNR==2{print $1}') node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```