# Create same master and working node in kubenetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am preparing `dev` environment and want to create a single host to be master and worker node for kubernetes.

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Hello @GovindaChaulagain , did provided answer help you? Do you need more explanation?

Comment: See [minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/)

Answer (score 1):

> The ***master node*** is responsible for running several Kubernetes processes that are absolutely necessary to run and manage the cluster properly. [[1]](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-kubernetes-cluster-what-are-worker-and-master-nodes)
>
> The ***worker nodes*** are the part of the Kubernetes clusters which actually execute the containers and applications on them. [[1]](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-kubernetes-cluster-what-are-worker-and-master-nodes)

---

> ***Worker nodes*** are generally more powerful than ***master nodes*** because they have to run hundreds of clusters on them. However, ***master nodes*** hold more significance because they manage the distribution of workload and the state of the cluster. [[1]](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-kubernetes-cluster-what-are-worker-and-master-nodes)

---

By removing taint you will be able to schedule pods on that node.

You should firstly check the present taint by running:

```yaml
kubectl describe node <nodename> | grep Taints
```

In case the present one is master node you should remove that taint by running:

```yaml
kubectl taint node <mastername> node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule-
```

---

References:
[[1] - What is Kubernetes cluster? What are worker and master nodes?](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-kubernetes-cluster-what-are-worker-and-master-nodes)

See also:

- [Creating a cluster with kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/),
- This four similar questions:

  1. [Master tainted - no pods can be deployed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56162944/master-tainted-no-pods-can-be-deployed)
  2. [Remove node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule taint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55191980/remove-node-role-kubernetes-io-masternoschedule-taint),
  3. [Allow scheduling of pods on Kubernetes master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43147941/allow-scheduling-of-pods-on-kubernetes-master)
  4. [Are the master and worker nodes the same node in case of a single node cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63967089/are-the-master-and-worker-nodes-the-same-node-in-case-of-a-single-node-cluster)
- [Taints and Tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/).

Comment: `Worker nodes are generally more powerful than master nodes because they have to run hundreds of clusters on them` - I guess `clusters` was meant to be `containers` or `pods`

Answer (score 0):

- The difference between master node and worker node is that "regular pods cannot be scheduled on a master node because of a taint"
- You just need to remove `node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule` taint so that pods can be scheduled on that (master) node.

Following is the command:

```
kubectl taint nodes <masternodename> node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule-
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the NoSchedule taint from the MASTER node.
I just spun up a kubeadm node and the taint is on my control-plane, not master.
So I did the following (sydney is the node name):

```
    $kubectl describe node sydney | grep Taints

    Taints:             node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane:NoSchedule
    
    $kubectl taint nodes sydney node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane:NoSchedule-

    node/sydney untainted
    
    $kubectl describe node sydney | grep Taints
    Taints:             <none>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).